# SystemJS error when importing modules into AngularJS - Anonymous System.register calls can only be made by modules loaded by SystemJS.import

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, systemjs

I'm upgrading an AngularJS app to Angular, using the standard ngUpgrade module. I've converted a service to Angular, and I need to downgrade it so I can use it in an existing AngularJS module. I'm trying to import 'downgradeInjectable' and the Angular service like this:

```
import { downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { MyService } from './app/my-service';

(function () {

    var myCtrl = ['myService', function (myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
        ...
    }];

    ... stateConfig here    

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', stateConfig])
        .controller('myController', myCtrl)
        .factory('myService', downgradeInjectable(MyService))

})();
```

The imports are recognised as valid by the TypeScript compiler, and it all compiles fine, however I now get this error in the console:

```
Invalid System.register call. Anonymous System.register calls can only be made by modules loaded by SystemJS.import and not via script tags.
```

In the transpiled code, the import is handled like this by SystemJS:

```
System.register(["@angular/upgrade/static", "./app/my-service"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
     ...
```

My other AngularJS code isn't using any imports, this is the first time I've introduced an 'import' in the existing AngularJS application. What do I need to do to import these modules successfully? I've reviewed similar errors however there's nothing that helps me or that matches this particular situation.

---

**Update:**

I'm loading the application by importing a main module using SystemJS in my main html file like this:

```
<script>
    System.import('/assets/js/app/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

The original TypeScript for the main.js file bootstraps the root *Angular 4* module:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

... and the root module is like this:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
... other imports

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, UpgradeModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent],
    providers: [ WindowRef, MyService]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
    }

    ngDoBootstrap() {
        var ngApp = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('ngApp');
        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [ngApp.value]);
    }
}
```

... which then bootstraps the AngularJS app, within the context of Angular.

---

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true
  },
  "include": [ "**/*.ts" ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

---

**Further update:**

Following the advice from @Aluan Haddad I'm now attempting to no import the root AngularJS declarations like this:

*main.ts*

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

**import root AngularJS declarations**
import '../app.js';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The original *app.ts* for the AngularJS declarations in app.js looks like this:

```
declare var angular: any;

(function () {

    angular
        .module('shared', ['shared.primaryNavigation', ...otherDependencies]);

    angular
        .module('shared.ui.router', ['ui.router']);

    angular
        .module('ngApp1', ['dependency']);

     angular
        .module('ngApp2', ['dependency']);
```

There's nothing in here that's *exporting* anything though, so I wouldn't expect the attempted import to work, and honestly I now have no idea what's going on with the module loading as I only know about importing named classes and the AngularJS app doesn't use any exports! I now get these errors in the console:

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'shared' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

So how should I be structuring this to successfully load the app? My script inclusions look like this:

```
<!-- Angular JS -->
<!-- Root Module Declarations -->
<!-- now commenting this out -->
<!--<script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>-->

<!-- Shared Config -->
<script src="/assets/js/shared/shared.config.js"></script>

<!-- Shared Directives -->
<script src="/assets/js/shared/directives/myDirective1.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/shared/directives/myDirective2.js"></script>

<!-- Shared Components -->
<script src="/assets/js/shared/modules/myModule1.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/shared/modules/myModule2.js"></script>


<!-- Shared Services -->
<script src="/assets/js/shared/services/myService1.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/shared/services/myService2.js"></script>
```

Comment: How are you loading the application?

Comment: Thanks Aluan, I've added details in the 'update' section of the question.

Comment: Load `ngApp` in `main` (`import './path/to/my-module';`). Remove any script tags that reference it. Alternately, a better approach would be to `export default angular.module('myModule')...;` and import it where it is used, in core.

Comment: Thanks Aluan, I've added a 'further update' to help you understand the structure of the app. I'm really not sure what it's possible to do when loading an AngularJS app through Angular so any explanations would be great! I'm really trying to understand what's going on with the module loading.

Comment: You can load arbitrary JavaScript files with your loader using `import './x'`. In the case of your AngularJS app (as written since you can use ES Modules with AngularJS but haven't except for the 1 with imports), these files contain JavaScript that references global variables. These files are imported for their side effects (`import 'x'` is known as a side-effecting-import). The `nomod` error means you need to `import '../shared'` in the same way.

Comment: Looking at your script tags would make answering this question easier.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and help, you don't know how much I appreciate it! I've added the script tags at the bottom of the 'further updated'.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help. That is not a lot of script tags by any means, so I would just replace them all with a series of equivalent imports. A preferable way would just be to make them all modules by having them export their values (some refactoring involved though). That is preferable because it makes the dependencies explicit and so the SystemJS loader will ensure that the order cannot be wrong (i.e. no nomod errors) but just importing them will work provided you match the working script tag order.

Comment: One more thing, be advised that while I have used both AngularJS with SystemJS and Angular with SystemJS, I've never written a hybrid application that combines them directly using `@angular/upgrade`. Might be some weird gotchas in there. I doubt it, but I cannot speak from experience with the upgrade library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164666/discussion-between-chris-halcrow-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: Thanks again for your help Aluan, your answer enabled me to fix the issue. I'm having another issue with SystemJS loading a module from node_modules. If you're able to help given your knowledge of module systems that would again be hugely appreciated! The question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674941/ngx-restangular-installed-in-node-modules-folder-404-when-importing-from-angul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the error because, a top level `import` or `export` makes a file into a module.

That causes TypeScript to transpile it as such.

An anonymous `System.register` module must be loaded by a loader that understands the format, typically SystemJS.

Now that it is a module, import it like any other

```
import './my-module';
```

and remove script tags that load it.

This can be improved

```
import { downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { MyService } from './app/my-service';

class MyCtrl {
    static $inject = ['myService'];
    constructor(readonly myService) {...}
}

... stateConfig here    

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', stateConfig])
    .controller('myController', MyCtrl)
    .factory('myService', downgradeInjectable(MyService));
```

To explain the error in more detail, SystemJS also defines a *named* `System.register` module format. This is the output format used (by default) in the [SystemJS Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) to emit bundles.

Comment: Thanks Aluan although I'm confused as to why you're suggesting this in the root Angular module - import ngApp from './my-module'. The 'my module' is the AngularJS module where I'm trying to add the Angular service, so why would I import it as 'ngApp'? The app that gets bootstrapped (ngApp) is determined dynamically and it loads the appropriate app module that's defined in my app.ts.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow my mistake. I thought it was a typo in your example.

Answer (score 2):

See the excellent answer from @Aluan Haddad which explains exactly why this error occurs. In my case I had to import my root Angular.js file via my main *Angular* 'main.ts' file so that everything including the module that's now been created will now load through SystemJS:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// importing root AngularJS module here
import '../app.js';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```